# ElasticSearch: combine multiple Match queries based on conditions

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

Starting writing a QueryBuilder for building queries to ElasticSearch.
I would like "must" clause combine multiple conditions, but it should only contain the conditions that I want to apply. I should use object initializer in order that I could save it for future reuse.
This is the code:

```
public class QueryBuilder
{
    public Query BuildQuery(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        var must = new List<MatchQuery>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
        {
            must.Add(new MatchQuery("firstName") { Query = firstName });
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
        {
            must.Add(new MatchQuery("lastName") { Query = lastName });
        }

        return new BoolQuery
        {
            Must = must as ICollection<Query>
        };
    }
}
```

But running SearchRequest with this query it returns ALL items, not only those which are equal to 'firstName' and 'lastName'.
I use: Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.9.2 and do not use Nest.